# Two variables of different interface type but are the instance of the same class in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

What is the `difference` between two variables of the different `interface` types but actually instantiate with the `same object`.

For example, Class A implements both interface I1 I2.

```
interface I1 {}
interface I2 {}
class A implements I1, I2 {
...
}
```

Then I cast an instance of Class A to an interface type I1 and cast another A to type I2

```
I1 a1 = new A();
I2 a2 = new A();
```

What is the difference between `a1` and `a2`? Will `a1` of type `I1` not be able to call methods declared the interface `I2?`

Comment: There is no difference between a1 and a1. There is a difference between a1 and a2 specifically what methods could be invoked.

Comment: Note that casting always **just reduces** the view to an object. It does not really **change** the type of an object. If you, for example, do something like `System.out.println(a1.getClass())` it will read something like `class A` although you have casted it to `I1`. However reducing the view is good for modularity because if you just need `I1` than you can always easily exchange the object with another implementation of `I1` in the future. Also the compiler prevents you from calling methods of `I2` after casting to `I1` because it can not be sure at compile time that `I1` is also an `I2`.

Comment: So in compact: `a1` and also `a2`, even after the casting, remain of type `A`, `I1` and also `I2`. However after casting the *real type* is hidden and the compiler prevents you from doing *unsafe* method calls without casting back.

Comment: I suggest you give I1 and I2c different methods, and play around with what they computer will let you do. Then think about why it might be letting you do or not do certain things.

Answer (score 1):

`a1` **and** `a2` **are the different objects.**

for example:

```
interface I1 {
  public void derp();
}
interface I2 {
  public void herp();
}
```

and you have

```
I1 a1 = new A();
I2 a2 = new A();
```

`a1` refers to the class implements `I1` so `a1` can only call method defined in `I1` which is `derp()`. It cannot call `derp()` because `derp()` is defined in `I2`. And `a2` can only call `herp()` but not `derp()` for the same reason.

**Note** : although `a1` and `a2` are different objects but they can have no difference if `class A` implements all methods in `I1` and `I2` then `a1` and `a2` can act the same. but they are still two distinctive objects

Answer (score 0):

Both `a1` and `a2` refer to objects of type `A`.  It's important to distinguish between the "declared type" of a variable, and the actual type of the object it refers to (if the variable isn't null).

When you declare

```
I1 a1 = <anything>;
```

or just

```
I1 a1;
```

The only thing the compiler knows about `a1` is that it must refer to some object that implements `I1`.  Thus, you can only call a method `a1.method(...)` if the method is declared for the interface `I1` (or a superinterface, or `Object`).  Also, `a1` can only be assigned to another variable declared as being `I1` (or a superinterface, or `Object`), and if you use it as a parameter

```
x.someOtherMethod(a1);
```

it is legal only if the parameter is of type `I1`, or a superinterface, or `Object`.

Note that initializing it to `new A()` doesn't make a difference.  For the purposes of "what the compiler is allowed to know about a variable", the initial expression is not taken into consideration.  (You could have code that assigns `a1` to an object of a different type.  But the same rule applies even if the variable is `final`.)

However, you can get the compiler to treat it as another type by casting.  It's always legal to cast an interface variable to any other interface, because it's always possible that some class, somewhere, could implement both interfaces.  Thus, this is legal:

```
I2 x = (I2)a1;
```

At runtime, the compiler will check to see if `a1` refers to an object that also implements `I2` in addition to `I1`.  If so, the cast succeeds.  If not, an exception is thrown.  Assuming there's no exception, `(I2)a1` can now be used in any way that any other `I2` can.  Thus, if `I2` defines a method `methodOfI2`, you can say

```
((I2)a1).methodOfI2(...parameters...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you got the answer. Like you said, you can only call the methods defined in I1 on a1, and only the methods defined in I2 for a2.

Think about it with a concrete example:

```
public class PetDog implements FeedableAnimal, PettableAnimal {
     ...
}
...
FeedableAnimal dog = new PetDog();
```

Now if I instantiate a PetDog as a FeedableAnimal, I cannot call any methods defined in PettableAnimal. That is because PetDog only behaves like a FeedableAnimal now. We have no way of knowing that PetDog is Pettable because we did not instantiate it as a PettableAnimal.

Clarification on terminology: We are not "casting" PetDog to a FeedableAnimal. We are just saying that at compile time, dog acts like a FeedableAnimal. At runtime, dog still takes on the defined behaviors in PetDog.

Comment: It is not accurate to say `PetDog` acts like a `FeedableAnimal`.  Saying `dog` acts like a `FeedableAnimal` is more accurate.  `PetDog` will always have the methods of both interfaces.

Comment: *We have no way of knowing that PetDog is Pettable* - we do have a way -  `instanceof` (and multiple other ways)